# Enumerate files in gogle team drive where admin is not part of

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to know if a Google drive domain admin can enumerate files in team drive where he is not a member? currently this seems not supported through drive rest api, I'm using below API call to enumerate files and the corresponding error response below. Please let me know if there is any alternative api call to achieve this.

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?teamDriveId=&corpora=teamDrive&fields=*&includeTeamDriveItems=true&supportsTeamDrives=true

```
{
"error": {
    "errors": [
        {
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "teamDriveMembershipRequired",
            "message": "The attempted action requires Team Drive membership."
        }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The attempted action requires Team Drive membership."
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You must take note of the following [Team Drives: Requirements & access levels](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337554?hl=en) before making any requests to Drive API.

> [Users with G Suite Basic](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337554#basic) cannot create or access Team Drives
>   unless they are invited by a member of an external organization that
>   has Team Drives.

Refer to the table below on what action you can do in every team drives if you are a member.

[image]

To learn more about Drive API methods, you can refer to the [Drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/).